# nginx - How to manage private directories

Tags: nginx, private

this is a very basic question, but I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to set it up. I have a basic nginx personal web server setup, which is pretty much as it is out of the box. I would like to host a page that utilizes a database that I would like to keep hidden. What is the best way to setup a private directory to store sensitive information, either a private subdirectory for that page, or a more site wide directory outside of public hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a subdirectory require a username and password by usng HTTP Basic Authentication with a `location` directive in your `nginx.conf`. Without the username or password, you wouldn't be able to access the directory.

It would be a good idea to have TLS working on your site beforehand, as if your site is unencrypted it is possible that someone can see your username/password.

You will be needing the `htpasswd` program installed. On some distributions the package containing it is called `apache2-utils`, on others it is `httpd-tools`. Replace `username` with the username you want. It will prompt you for a password.

```
htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/htpasswd username
```

- Multiple users can be created by repeating the command with alternate usernames.

Then, in your `nginx.conf` file inside your server block, add the location directive below, replacing `/privatedir` with the directory you wish to protect, and `Private Directory` with the message you want to show on the login prompt:

```
location /privatedir {
    auth_basic "Private Directory";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
}
```

Restart `nginx` and your directory `/privatedir` as shown in the example above will require a username and password to access. If none is given, or it is not a valid username and password, it will give a HTTP 401 Unauthorized message.

For more information on HTTP Basic Authentication, be sure to check [nginx's documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html)